# IServiceProvider garbage collection / disposal

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, .net-core

I was trying to debug a memory leak in my app (see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196496/recurring-tasks-in-net-core-console-app)) and have encountered a smilingly wrong behavior.

In this code (simplified snippet, of course):

```
    while (true)
    {
        using (var context = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataContext>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
```

Memory consumption grows **rapidly**.

If I comment out service spawn, memory consumption is stable.

```
    while (true)
    {
        // using (var context = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataContext>())
        // {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        // }
    }
```

Service was registered as *transient*.

My understanding is that `using` statement is responsible for disposing a service. `var context` is created in the scope of `while` and should be destroyed when new iteration begins.

My first thought was that GC just does not do its job frequently enough, but does not frequency increase when amount of consumed memory increases?

Why am I wrong?

Comment: Does the GC ever collect?

Comment: @khargoosh it should but does not seem to. The question is why.

Comment: Is it possible that `_serviceProvider` does not correctly implement `IDisposable` or does not release any resources? Do you at any time receive an exception?

Comment: @khargoosh No exceptions (but I feel like if I let it grow infinitely I will get some).` _serviceProvide` which is `IServiceProvider` should not be disposed. The service that it returns (`IDataContext` a wrapper for `DbContext`) does implement it.

Comment: Of course, sorry.  You should try to break it!  If you have such a suspicion, test it.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? Without that, it's hard to reproduce what you're seeing to actually diagnose it.

Comment: @DmytroBogatov how did you go with further testing?

Comment: @khargoosh actually, I figured it out. The problem is in the IoC container of Microsoft and there is an issue for that. I will probably answer my own question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After days of fighting the problem, I finally derived the answer. In short, the issue is that Microsoft DI container **does not dispose** transient services, it keeps references on them.

Here is the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/456#issuecomment-292331341) on github.

The developers do not plan to fix it since the cost (complexity and hackiness) of fixing overweighs the benefits.

Suggested workaround is using **scoped** service instead of the **transient** one.

Here is an example code, see more in [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/456#issuecomment-292331341).

```
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
using (var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataContext>())
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just want to point out, that it may not be enough to switch from a transient to a scoped service. In my application that wasn't even needed at all.

My problem was that, as you already said in your answer, the **ServiceProvider keeps track of all objects** it created.
Having a long running application with a container that is never disposed causes a huge memory consumption. Even if the container only creates transient objects (that are not even IDisposable) which quickly run "out of scope". Since the ServiceProvider is still keeping track of those objects the GC can't do its work.

Consider using a scoped ServiceProvider as suggested for the fact that disposing it will end the lifetime of all of its children (**scoped and transient**) too.
Don’t let containers (children) grow out of bounds. Use scoped ServiceProvider even for transient objects.